# SQLite Failed to Parse The Row

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

I tried to add data to SQLite and then read it, but when I run the apps its force closed..

here is part of the logcat which I assume the problem

> 12-24 01:57:19.462 15349-15349/com.eldarcreative.portalbola E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.eldarcreative.portalbola, PID: 15349
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.eldarcreative.portalbola/com.eldarcreative.portalbola.Favorit}: org.jetbrains.anko.AnkoException: Class parser for com.eldarcreative.portalbola.Database.FavoriteTeam failed to parse the row:

This is my database code

```
db.createTable(FavoriteTeam.TEAM_TABLE, true,
        FavoriteTeam.ID to INTEGER + PRIMARY_KEY + AUTOINCREMENT,
        FavoriteTeam.TEAM_ID to TEXT,
        FavoriteTeam.STR_TEAM to TEXT,
        FavoriteTeam.TEAM_BADGE to TEXT,
        FavoriteTeam.TEAM_MANAGER to TEXT,
        FavoriteTeam.STADIUM to TEXT,
        FavoriteTeam.DESCRIPTION to TEXT,
        FavoriteTeam.TEAM_BANNER to TEXT)
```

here the code where I add the data to database

```
    private fun addToFavorite() {
    try {
        database.use {
            insert(
                FavoriteTeam.TEAM_TABLE,
                    FavoriteTeam.TEAM_ID to id_team,
                FavoriteTeam.STR_TEAM to txtdetailnama.text,
                FavoriteTeam.TEAM_BADGE to strTeamBadge,
                FavoriteTeam.TEAM_MANAGER to txtnamamanager.text,
                FavoriteTeam.STADIUM to txtnamastadion.text,
                FavoriteTeam.DESCRIPTION to teamOverview.text,
                FavoriteTeam.TEAM_BANNER to strTeamBanner

            )
        }

        toast ("Data Telah Di Simpan"  )
    } catch (e: SQLiteConstraintException) {
        toast("Error: ${e.message}")
    }
}
```

and this code is when I tried to display it

```
   fun defaultfave(){
    rvfavorite.layoutManager= GridLayoutManager(this,3)
    database.use {
        favoriteams.clear()
        val hasil1 = select(FavoriteTeam.TEAM_TABLE)
        val datafav1 = hasil1.parseList(classParser<FavoriteTeam>())
        favoriteams.addAll(datafav1)
        rvfavorite.adapter = FavoriteTeamAdapter(favoriteams)

    }
```

FavouriteTeam is :-

```
@Parcelize
data class FavoriteTeam(
    val id: Long?,
    val idTeam: String,
    val str_team : String,
    val team_manager : String,
    val stadium:String,
    val deskription : String,
    val team_baner:String,
    val team_badge:String,
    val urlImage: String
): Parcelable {
    companion object {
        const val TEAM_TABLE: String = "TEAM_TABLE"
        const val ID: String = "ID_"
        const val TEAM_ID: String = "TEAM_ID"
        const val STR_TEAM:String="STR_TEAM"
        const val TEAM_BADGE: String = "TEAM_BADGE"
        const val TEAM_MANAGER:String ="TEAM_MANAGER"
        const val STADIUM :String ="STADIUM"
        const val DESCRIPTION:String ="DESCRIPTION"
        const val TEAM_BANNER:String="TEAM_BANNER"

    }
}
```

but it's failed, anyone knew why and how to fix it

Comment: Can you provide us with FavoriteTeam

Comment: Solved .. After traced the code

Comment: so what's the problem exactly ?

Comment: In FavoriteTeam data class i should.add question mark after string. I.e  val idteam:string?'